# SharePoint 2010 Customized List form using infopath doesn't inherit new fields automatically

Tags: infopath

This situations has really got me stuck. I have a SharePoint 2010 list that I would like to save as a template. The list is based on Task list template and has a customized forms using Customize forms option and infopath. I was able to successfully publish the form and until this point everything works like a charm.

The problem I am experiencing starts here though. When I update the list fields like add or delete a field, it doesn't update the form automatically. I have to customize the form again which means each time some other department would like to use my customized task list and add or delete the fields in it they would have to customize the form or atleast use the customize forms option and open the forms using infopath so that fields can be updated.

I am not sure how default forms always gets updated automatically when you add or remove the fields from the list. but does anyone have any idea how can we enable the similar feature with customized form.

Please let me know if you have more questions.

Thanks for your answers... I appreciate everybody's time here.

Answer (score 2):

When you customize a form, it converts a list form web part into a dataform web part.  The advantage of the list form (default) web part as columns are automatically added, updated (if the column type is changed), or deleted.

The dataforms convert the list form that exists at that time by replacing the nice automatic updating list form with the static dataform.  As such, any additions or customizations have to made to the static form.

It isn't the most elegant answer, that's just how it is.  Generally speaking, anytime you customize a form in Sharepoint, that's what will happen.  Alternatively if you leave the form in its default nature, you can customize it with jQuery/SPServices/CSS overrides to keep the auto modification piece in play and just update your scripts as things change.

Either way you have to modify code to account for the form changes.

Comment: Thank you Eric, Well, most of my customizations are adding validations on certain fields like if they are closing the task than they have to have close date and certain other fields. Is there any other way, I can stop SharePoint from changing it from List form web part to dataform web part.

Comment: If you're only customizing the form for validation purposes, you can use javascript/jQuery and tie into the PreSaveAction to handle the validation, http://ghamson.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/useful-javascript-function-presaveaction-sp2010-sharepoint-ps2010-projectserver-in/

Comment: Thanks Eric, yeah thats a good option. I guess I have some more learning to do.